# Specify that a remote process created by wmi should interact with the desktop

Tags: c#, wmi

I know I can create a remote process via WMI, something like:

```
        object[] theProcessToRun = { "notepad.exe" };
        var path = new ManagementPath(String.Format(@"\\{0}\root\cimv2", "win7test-hyperv"));
        var scope = new ManagementScope(path);
        var theClass = new ManagementClass(scope, new ManagementPath("Win32_Process"), new ObjectGetOptions());
        theClass.InvokeMethod("Create", theProcessToRun);
```

But can I specify that should interact with the desktop (like psexec's -i)? I'd also like to be able to specify what user session the UI should interact with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons the [Win32_Process.Create method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389388%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) cannot be used to start an interactive process remotely.